# Card number is required- authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I am trying to integrate authorize.net payment gateway in my website. My code works fine in testing mode but when I switch to live mode it gives me the following error:

```
[errorCode:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionResponseType\ErrorsAType\ErrorAType:private] => 33
                            [errorText:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionResponseType\ErrorsAType\ErrorAType:private] => Expiration date is required.
```

I double check my card info and it is correct but still receive same error response. It means the card number I passed is not caught by the endpoint of the api. Here is my code for passing card info:

```
   $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
        $creditCard->setCardNumber("16 DIGIT CARD NUMBER");
        $creditCard->setExpirationDate("2019-7");
        $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
        $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);
```

For security I hide my card number. Any idea to overcome this error is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the format for your expiration date: http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#payment-transactions-charge-a-credit-card

Comment: Expiration date format I modified but not solve problem?

Comment: Try `2019-07`..

Answer (score -1):

The customer’s credit card expiration date format must be one of the following:

MMYY, 
MM/YY, 
MM-YY, MMYYYY, 
MM/YYYY, 
MM-YYYY

Reference: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#payment-transactions-charge-a-credit-card

Comment: Maybe they changed it. "String, 7 characters. Use XML gMonthYear (YYYY-MM) formatting."